# Simple question about the domain of the marginal density function

Tags: probability-distributions, solution-verification, density-function

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be continuous random variables with joint density function $f(x, y)=15y$ for $x^2\le y\le x$ and $0$ otherwise. Find the marginal density function of $Y$.

The answer I found was $15y^{3/2}(1-y^{1/2})$ for $x^2\le y\le x$. I used the same $y-$bounds as the joint density function because I thought that that's someone one needs to do. However, the correct $y-$bounds are $0\le y\le 1$. Why did we change these bounds? Could someone please explain what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

The marginal density function oof $Y$ is given by
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)\,dx
$$
It can *not* depends on $x$; this is a function in $y$.

The key thing is to figure out the region where $f$ is not zero:
$$
S=\{(x,y)\mid x^2<y<x\}
$$
It is very easy to visualize the set by drawing a picture. See below.

Observe that for any $y>1$ or $y<0$, $f(x,y)=0$. (This is why the correct "bounds" for $y$ is $0\le y\le 1$.)

Now, given $0\le y\le1$, you want to integrate on $x$. The bounds for $x$ should be given by
$$
y<x<\sqrt{y}
$$
and thus the integral is
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_y^{\sqrt{y}}15 y\,dx,\quad 0\le y\le 1
$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! If we were trying to find the marginal density function for $X$ instead, would the bounds for $x$ be $0\le x \le 1$ as well (since, by your logic, the bounds of $x$ shouldn't depend on $Y$)?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson: you are welcome! That is correct; the marginal density $f_X(x)$ does not depend on $y$.